# Using provided Cross-Sectional survey weights in a Longitudinal model

Tags: r, statistics, survey

I'm running a longitudinal model using data from 3 waves of a survey.

I want to use the pre-calculated survey weights provided but I only have cross-sectional weights (1 per wave).

Do I weight each dataset first using the survey weights, and then merge them together? Or is there some way I should calculate a new longitudinal weight using these given weights?

I'm working in R and this is my code so far but as you can see there is only 1 weight included.

```r
svydesign(data$psu, probs=NULL, strata = data$strata, variables = NULL, fpc=NULL,
          data = data, nest = FALSE, check.strata = TRUE, weights=data$i_indinui_xw,pps=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the weights to add up to the population size, so you will typically need to divide weights by 3 if you have 3 waves.  See, for example, [this advice](https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes/tutorials/module3.aspx) on combining multiple waves of the NHANES survey.